# How to not sum all row in table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table :

```
+---------+-----+
| id_user | pax |
+---------+-----+
|       2 |   2 |
|       2 |   2 | 
|       3 |   2 |
|       3 |   2 |
+---------+-----+
```

So i have a 4 row of data

- id_user = 2, with 2 rows of data,
- id_user = 3, with 2 rows of data

How do i sum just 1 of each row id_user ? so the result of sum i want to get is 4 not 8

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: 'How do i sum just 1 of each row id_user' - is ambiguous you may mean sum both rows for each id_user(giving 2 rows in the result) or you may mean select 1 row for each id_user and provide a total (giving 3 rows) or you may mean select 1 row for each user and sum them (giving 1 total row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT
    id_user,
    SUM(pax)

FROM
    myTable

GROUP BY
    id_user
```

See this [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7905d5/2) for example using your data.

[Here is some documentation.](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `row_number()`:

```
select sum(pax)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id_user order by pax) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

`row_number()` gives you flexibility on *which* value to use (in this case it chooses the minimum `pax` value).  It also allows you to include other information, such as the total count of rows.

Note:  Have a column such as `pax` repeated on different rows suggests that your data is not normalized.  Sometimes this happens when working with summary tables.  However, more often, it suggests a problem with the data model that should be fixed by having a table with one row per `id_user` and `pax` value.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are after but here's some possibilities.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id_user int,pax int);
insert into t values
(       2 ,   2 ),
(       2 ,   2 ), 
#(       2 ,   3 ), 
(       3 ,   2 ),
(       3 ,   2 );


select sum(pax) sumpax
from 
(select distinct id_user,pax from t) s;

+--------+
| sumpax |
+--------+
|      4 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

select id_user,sum(pax) sumpax
from
(select distinct id_user,pax from t) s
group by id_user with rollup;

+---------+--------+
| id_user | sumpax |
+---------+--------+
|       2 |      2 |
|       3 |      2 |
|    NULL |      4 |
+---------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select id_user,sum(pax) sumpax
from t
group by id_user with rollup;

+---------+--------+
| id_user | sumpax |
+---------+--------+
|       2 |      4 |
|       3 |      4 |
|    NULL |      8 |
+---------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```